# Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS problem after upgrade from linux 4.4.0-124 to 4.4.0-159

Tags: 16.04, drivers, upgrade

Looks like something went wrong because the wireless network drivers are not working, also the sound is not working, and the package manager is not able to fix anything because the hardware drivers are wrong/missing?
I had to reboot, then advanced options and boot with 4.4.0-124 version and everything is working there.
How can I fix this or erase the last upgrade 4.4.0-159 from my computer or change the boot menu so my first choice will be 4.4.0-124?
Please let me know if you need more info on this.

Comment: Does HWE kernel work better? https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: Did not check this, i am not using the new version because Its useless for me,,

Comment: It is good to use latest kernel, if it works. Maybe the problem has been fixed in later kernel. It might be good, if you boot the latest kernel and run "ubuntu-bug linux" if the problem is present and you can get network connection by other means.